# PHP - Sort array elements based on another array's elements :)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

so I have two arrays. one of them looks like this (it's values or the number of elements can change):

```
array('4dec' , 'def3', 'a3d6', 'd12f');
```

and the other:

```
array(array('id' => 'd12f', 'name' => 'John'),
      array('id' => 'a5f1', 'name' => 'Kathy'),
      array('id' => 'def3', 'name' => 'Jane'),
      array('id' => 'a3d6', 'name' => 'Amy'),
      array('id' => '4dec', 'name' => 'Mary'),      
      array('id' => 'ecc2', 'name' => 'Fred'));
```

(this one shouldn't change, elements and values are the same every time).

notice the first one has a few elements from the 2nd one.
How can I sort the 2nd array based on the elements from the 1st one?

so basically, in this case the 2nd array should become:

```
array(array('id' => '4dec', 'name' => 'Mary'),
      array('id' => 'def3', 'name' => 'Jane'),
      array('id' => 'a3d6', 'name' => 'Amy'),
      array('id' => 'd12f', 'name' => 'John'),
      array('id' => 'a5f1', 'name' => 'Kathy'),
      array('id' => 'ecc2', 'name' => 'Fred'));
```

(the elements that exist in the 1st one are moved at the top, in the same order as the 1st, and the others are left alone).

Comment: Are there always only 'id' and 'name' properties for the data array? If so we could discard these explicit key names and use the first array as an index to the second with no sorting needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stability was a twist, as PHP doesn't respect that any longer, but a little extra work keeps the sort stable.

```
$order_by = array('4dec' , 'def3', 'a3d6', 'd12f');

$data = array(array('id' => 'd12f', 'name' => 'John'),
              array('id' => 'a5f1', 'name' => 'Kathy'),
              array('id' => 'def3', 'name' => 'Jane'),
              array('id' => 'a3d6', 'name' => 'Amy'),
              array('id' => '4dec', 'name' => 'Mary'),      
              array('id' => 'ecc2', 'name' => 'Fred'));

// create a lookup table for sorted order to avoid repeated searches
$order_index = array_flip($order_by);

// create a lookup table for original order: in PHP 4.1.0 usort became unstable
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
$orig_order_by = array_map(function($a){return $a['id'];}, $data);
$orig_index = array_flip($orig_order_by);

// sort values by specified order, with stability
$compare = function($a, $b) use (&$order_index, &$orig_index) {
    $aid = $a['id'];
    $bid = $b['id'];

    $ai = $order_index[$aid];
    $bi = $order_index[$bid];

    if ($ai === null and $bi === null) { // original sort order for stability
        return $orig_index[$aid] - $orig_index[$bid];
    }
    if ($ai === null) { return 1; }
    if ($bi === null) { return -1; }

    return $ai - $bi;
};
usort($data, $compare);
var_dump($data);
```