# Sort an array by using the same order of another one

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays containing starting poker hold'em hands.

One is composed of unordered values.

```
$array1 = array("65s","AA","J9s","AA","32s");
//the cards can be repeated here as you see there are 2 "AA"
```

and the other one that should be used as a model to order the first array:

```
$array_sorted = array("AA","KK","AKs"...);
//here the cards are not repeated
```

I'd like to re-order $array1 with the sort used in $array_sorted,

it should return an array like:

```
$array1 = array("AA","AA","J9s","65s","32s");
```

I have completely no idea on how to accomplish this. Maybe by using some "user defined sorting method"? Really don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Don't you just want asort? http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: I don't think asort() would do the trick, I need to sort $array1 by using the order in $array_sorted.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, you'd want usort then. http://us2.php.net/usort

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Sort array elements based on another array's elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197598/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, and [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) is the "user-defined sorting method" you're looking for. Something like this ought to work for you:

PHP >= 5.3

```
// Firstly this will be faster if the hands are the keys in the array instead
// of the values so we'll flip them with array_flip.
$array_sorted = array_flip( array( 'AA', 'KK', 'AKs', /* ... */ ) );
// => array( 'AA' => 0, 'KK' => 1, 'AKs' => 2, ... )

// your hands
$array1 = array( '65s', 'AA', 'J9s', 'AA', '32s' );

$array1_sorted = usort(
  $array1,

  // The comparison function 
  function($a, $b) {
    // If $a is AA and $b is J9s then
    // $array_sorted[ 'AA' ] - $array_sorted[ 'J9s' ]
    // will evaluate to a negative number, telling PHP that $a (AA)
    // is "smaller" than $b (J9s) and so goes first.
    return $array_sorted[ $a ] - $array_sorted[ $b ];
  }
);
```

PHP < 5.3

```
function sorting_function($a, $b){
  $array_sorted = array_flip( array( 'AA', 'KK', 'AKs', /* ... */ ) );

  return $array_sorted[ $a ] - $array_sorted[ $b ];
}

$array1 = array( '65s', 'AA', 'J9s', 'AA', '32s' );

$array1_sorted = usort( $array1, 'sorting_function' );
```

Comment: I'm testing it, but since I'm using it into a method of a class it returns this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /Applications/MAMP/www/class2.php on line 1312

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Your version does not support anonymous functions, declare the function outside of the `usort()` and and call it like this `usort($array1, "function_name")`

Comment: This is a scope problem. `$array_sorted` doesn't exist within the scope of `sorting_function`. I'm trying to think of the best workaround.

Comment: I've edited it to move `$array_sorted` into `sorting_function`. I don't think there are any big downsides to this. If this was my project I'd likely end up building a class around this and keeping $array_sorted as a static variable but that may be overkill for your project.

Comment: Thank you! I've resolved, there was a problem into $array_sorted; Your code work perfectly. ;-)