# Split an array and add a letter to the end of every piece

Tags: php, arrays

The title maybe counfusing, I'll try to explain with an example:

I have an array containing all the possible 1326 starting hands in texas hold'em *sorted in order of strength. *

```
$array = array("AA","AA",..."KK","KK",..."AKs",.."AKo",..);
```

I'd like to create a new array by splitting every hand into the 2 cards and add to them a letter (the suit).
The suit are 4: **c,s,d,h** so the final array should become something like:

```
$array1 = array(array("Ac","As"), array("As","Ad"),..., array("Ac","Kc"), array("Ac","Ks"));
```

P.S. When in $array i use the sintax AK *s* it means the same suit, the *o* stands for offsuited.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

$array1 should contain all the 1326 combinations *of two cards* possible with a deck of 52 cards. http://pastebin.com/kde4qjLD

The sorting of $array should be in order of strength (Expected value of each hand).
The array with the right sorting order can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ydfd08Cw

```
$array1 = array(
    array( "As", "Ad" ),
    array( "Ad", "Ac" ),
    array( "Ac", "Ah" ),
    array( "Ah", "As" ),
    array( "As", "Ac" ),
    array( "Ac", "Ad" ),
    array( "As", "Ks" ),
    array( "Ad", "Kd" ),
//etc
);
```

Comment: Please describe it more.  Texas thingy is localized. Many a user wont understand it.

Comment: Described :) Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// our Card like Ah or 2c
class Card {

  /**
   * @var string 'A','K','Q','J','T','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2'
   */
  public $sign;

  /**
   * @var string 'h','c','d','s'
   */
  public $suit;

  public function __construct($sign, $suit) {
    $this->sign = $sign;
    $this->suit = $suit;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->sign.$this->suit;
  }

  /**
   * Computes a unique-hash of two play cards
   * 
   * returns something like AhAs (ordered by Sign of the Cards)
   * if the sign of the cards is the same, it is ordered by suite
   *
   * every hash from a tupel of cards should return the same hash!
   * @returns string
   */
  public function hash(Card $cardB) {
    $cardA = $this;

    if ($cardA->sign === $cardB->sign) {
      $cmp = strcmp($cardA->suit, $cardB->suit);
    } else {
      $cmp = strcmp($cardA->sign, $cardB->sign);
    }

    return $cmp > 0
        ? $cardA.$cardB
        : $cardB.$cardA
    ;
  }
}

// create all possible cards
$cards = array();
foreach (array('A','K','Q','J','T','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2') as $sign) {
  foreach (array('h','c','d','s') as $suit) {
    $cards[] = new Card($sign,$suit);
  }
}

/*
  create combinations from all cards ($card) with all cards ($secondcard)
  we don't want to combine:
    - cards which are the same
    - cards which have alreay been combined (saved in index)
*/
$index = array();
$combinations = array();
foreach ($cards as $card) {
  foreach ($cards as $secondCard) {
    if ($card !== $secondCard && !array_key_exists($hash = $card->hash($secondCard), $index)) {
      $combinations[] = array($card, $secondCard);
      $index[$hash] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}

// print results
var_dump(count($combinations));
foreach ($combinations as $cards) {
  print $cards[0].$cards[1]."\n";
}
```

I hope the comments explain the way it works.
Of course there is a nicer (much more complicated way) to do this. The "key" in this thing is to create the unique-hash from two cards, so that every touple from the same cards returns the same hash.

Hope this helps to understand

P.S.: this wasts time + space but it is understandable

Comment: I'm testing it, it gives this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 77, maybe because I'm using PHP 5.2? How can I solve that?

Comment: i updated the sourcecode, but you could have figured this out by your own.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! However it should return a sorted list of those 1326 hands, the sorting order is the one provided in $array (In order of strength). Maybe this question should be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885412/sort-an-array-by-using-the-same-order-of-another-one

Comment: yeah, this task is up to you. You should use uasort() and write your own sorting custom function for your order. It should be easy with the cards class I implemented for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$suits = array('c','s','d','h');
$faces = array('A','K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2');
function generate_permutations($elems){
    $result = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($elems);$i++){
        for ($j=$i+1;$j<count($elems);$j++){
            $result[] = array($elems[$i],$elems[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$cards = array();
foreach ($suits as $suit){
    foreach ($faces as $face){
        $cards[] = $face.$suit;
    }
}
$new_array = generate_permutations($cards);
```

Comment: I'm testing it but doens't work as expected since it gives an array with duplicates. If there is "As"-"Ac", there shouldn't exist "Ac"-"As". Any idea to solve this?

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Texas hold'em, so does it have any more restrictions?

Comment: No I think that's all! :D $new_array should consist of 1326 different hands.

Comment: Ehm... I hate to say this but it doesn't work as expected either.
The output array should be in the format presented in the question, now it has 1326 arrays containg each 6 values;

Comment: I think you are going in wrong direction. What's 1326 starting hands? Is it all possible permutation of some set of cards?

Comment: It should return something like this: http://pastebin.com/kde4qjLD
These are the 1326 possible combinations, I want them splitted and sorted as in $array.

Comment: Rewritten. At the moment it is ordered by the first card. Try to play with the order of `foreach` and `for` loops to get other sortings.

Comment: Nice!! :D But now it has to be in the same order of $array; really appreciate your efforts! +1

Comment: How did you get that initial sorting? It hard to see any pattern there.

Comment: They're sorted by expected value (the strength), as you can see here:http://www.tightpoker.com/poker_hands.html

Comment: Are you able to calculate the strength by yourself?

Comment: I don't think so, there's not a particular algorithm. Those charts are based on real hands played; the other option should be doing simulations... too complex for this task.
Something like usort won't do the trick in your opinion?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885412/sort-an-array-by-using-the-same-order-of-another-one

Maybe is useful

Comment: if you need the chart, I've created a PHP array here: http://pastebin.com/ydfd08Cw

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray=array();
while (true) {
  $a=array_shift($array);
  if (!$a) break;
  $b=substr($a,1);
  $a=substr($a,0,1);
  $newarray[]=array (
    $a.'c', $a.'s',$a.'d',$a.'h',
    $b.'c', $a.'s',$b.'d',$b.'h'
  );
}
```