# PHP arrays and order sorting

Tags: php, arrays

I have to create delivery routes for shipping orders for different clients all over the country. The routes are fixed, meaning that the delivery points inside each route are arranged in a specific order, and the mileage between points in route are defined in a matrix of the route. So, every point in route has the number of km between every point from the route

So, I have the route 'Route_A' defined with the points:

```
Route_A = ['Point_1','Point_2','Point_3','Point_4', 'Point_5']
```

The matrix form is something like this:

```
            Warehouse   Point_1 Point_2 Point_3 Point_4 Point_5
Warehouse   0           10      20      30      40      50
Point_1     10          0       15      25      35      45
Point_2     20          15      0       5       20      70
Point_3     30          25      5       0       50      25
Point_4     40          35      20      50      0       10
Point_5     50          45      70      25      10      0
```

The planner selects points from route (not always a full route) and I want the system to be able to calculate the total distance for given route

So, I could have a delivery route (with points from route above) like this (the order of the route must also be rearranged to look like 'Route_A'):

```
delivery_route = ['Point_3', 'Point_2', 'Point_5', ,'Point_3', 'Point_2','Point_5','Point_1']
```

I would like to know if this could be done easily without having to write a messy php code

Comment: What's the question?  Is there something that isn't working?

Comment: Just added the question, thx!

Comment: Have you tried anything? How are the distances stored? (Your matrix : database? arrays?)

Comment: Need to know what format the matrix you are given to provide the most efficient answer.

Comment: All data is stored in MySQL database, the distances are stored in a table like this:
{id | route_id | pFrom | pTo | distance}
where pFrom and pTo are id's of the points in route

Comment: And potentially how big can the data set get to to perform one lookup?

Comment: There are already 200 routes and over 1000 points in routes

Comment: this seem to work: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AXVwT6KM
decide yourself if it is messy or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this:

```
$delivery_length = 0;
for ($i = 1, $route_len = count($delivery_route); $i < $route_len; $i++) {
    $delivery_length += $distance_matrix[$delivery_route[$i-1]][$delivery_route[$i]];
}
```

It iterates the list of locations in the route and adds up the distance from the previous stop to the current one.

Comment: Yes, that was my original thought, but, then I realized that the solution has to be more complex, keeping in mind that the points given from the planner are not in the right order

Comment: You can use `uasort` on `delivery_route` and use the `route_a` list as the priority list.  See [this example](http://php.net/usort#25360) from the PHP documentation.

Comment: I found something useful for sorting the user array: [link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885412/sort-an-array-by-using-the-same-order-of-another-one)]