# PHP sort one array's keys and values based on the order of keys from a second array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I looked through the first 15 questions on stackoverflow related to this question and unfortunately none of the questions matched mine.

I have two arrays.  The first has the order that I need the second to be in:

```
Array
(
    [1] => name
    [2] => value
    [3] => cost
    [4] => customer
    [5] => date
    [6] => country

)
```

My second array has the possibility of being formatted in one of many ways, but this is an example:

```
Array
(
    [country] => US
    [customer] => Acme
    [date] => 2016-04-08
    [name] => Brian
    [value] => 0
    [cost] => 22

)
```

I need to sort this array so that it follows the same *order* as the sorting array, and ends up looking like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Brian
    [value] => 0
    [cost] => 22
    [customer] => Acme
    [date] => 2016-04-08
    [country] => US
)
```

The post that has made the most sense to me is [PHP - Sort array elements based on another array's elements :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197598/php-sort-array-elements-based-on-another-arrays-elements) which works by utilizing `array_flip()` on the first sorting array to create a lookup table, but from there it breaks down and does not work for me.

How would I go about this?

## Edit

I had already looked at the post that this question has been marked a duplicate of, and the code did not work for me.

Here is that sample:

```
//$x = my incorrectly-sorted array in its entirety
$p = array($columns_list[1], $columns_list[2], $columns_list[3], $columns_list[4], $columns_list[5], $columns_list[6], $columns_list[7], $columns_list[8], $columns_list[9], $columns_list[10]);            

    $array = array_map(function($x)use($p){      
      return array_replace(array_flip($p), $x);
    }, $array);
```

Comment: @u_mulder thanks so much for your constructive comment!

Comment: Since you have just a single array, you just have to use `$result = array_replace(array_flip($yourOrder), $yourData);`